# How to include taxonomy.php in functions.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Does exist a way to unclude file `wp-admin/taxonomy.php` in `functions.php`, not using `ABSPATH` constant?

Similar situation with `WP PLUGIN DIR`, how to include plugin file in `functions.php` not using this constant?

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve. Are you able to include the files using the constants you've provided? If so, why do you want to remove the constants?

Comment: Yes, I can include files, using constants, but we can not pass moderation, because of using these constants. It is nessesery do this but without using constants

Comment: What is "moderation"?

Comment: It is a theme, so it must pass moderation, they would not see mentioned constants in the theme body